# How do I get a dead Uruk to come back

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

A previously long-since killed uruk's body is lying in the "Sauron's Army" menu, and has been there for a while. Never moving or going away. I know that this means (since his head isn't on a pike) that he should be coming back, but he's not. He hasn't popped in while I'm running around, doing a mission, or even when I've been hit to near death on my knee (sometimes they appear when you're about to die).

So, anybody have a clue?

(Funnily enough, this Uruk has the title of Shaman, although this is now my second case of this happening.)

Answer (score 2):

The system of Shadow of Mordor isn't very clear on that but basically the short answer is:

**You can't force an Uruk to return**

If his head is on a pike, the Uruk is dead and won't return.

If the Uruk is just laying on the ground **there's a chance** he'll come back. It isn't 100% sure he will come back and sometimes the system takes a while to renew fallen Uruks with promoted ones or new ones.

You have to wait and see if he comes back. If he does let us know in the comments.

Comment: Same guy here (I don't know if it will show that).

So, just for information's sake I guess, I'll describe the situation. That Uruk has been laying there for a long while now. Dead, and never going away. This has happened twice to me, like I've said before, and perhaps it's a bug. I've seen a few other bugs. So, as of yet, no change. But thanks for answering!

Comment: In a complex system like the Nemesis System things like this are bound to happen. It's not that bad of a bug so no big deal. If you want to accept the answer be at will. But I understand that there is not much information about this subject.

Answer (score 1):

For 1 and only 1 Uruk Captain your answer is: **Board the Boat**

If you are in the 2nd half of the game (have defeated The Hammer), I've noticed that the Nemesis system keeps at least 1 "not dead yet" captain "in reserve".  I believe this is the captain who will eventually control the crowd of uruks you encounter prior to facing The Tower.  The game seems to be able to change its mind about *which* captain is kept in reserve, but the reserve doesn't seem to go away until The Tower is defeated.